Is ので here being shortned from something else?
耀「自分から半休にして服買いに行くって言ってたろ？　今日はもうそれで帰宅して体も休めとけ」
由弦「とはいえ私はずっと伊波さんが看病してくれましたし、その間休めているので…」
耀「俺はお前と違って鍛えて丈夫なの。とはいえ…」
This a back and forth between two colleagues. I generally understood the whole meaning which can be summed up as
"For today , go home and rest"
"Still, you have been nursing me all this time."
"I'm not like you, I'm pretty tough"
However what caught my attention is this part "、その間休めているので…」" my first reading was that the character is insisting he did rest during that time (so there is no need for further rest), but based on the other answer, could he perhaps be saying that the other character didn't rest instead? のではなかった?

This "ので…" is just ", so...". You need to understand what 由弦 wants to say based on the broader context, but something like "it's not me but you who should rest" may be implied.
